# Will a stored procedure fail if one of the queries inside it fails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a stored procedure with a `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement.

Nothing is inside a transaction block. There are no `Try/Catch` blocks either.
I also have `XACT_ABORT` set to OFF.

If the `INSERT` fails, is there a possibility for the `UPDATE` to still happen?

The reason the `INSERT` failed is because I passed in a null value to a column which didn't allow that. I only have access to the exception the program threw which called the stored procedure, and it doesn't have any severity levels in it as far as I can see.

Comment: That depends on the error-handling code in your procedure: if you have `TRY...CATCH` blocks.

Comment: No Try Catch blocks either

Comment: Who controls the stored proc? Your edits are a little unclear, it sounds like you have changed your question. Your original question was: Can the update still happen? Answer: Yes. You've added some additional statements, which don't change that answer, without changing what you are asking for. Is your new question now meant to be: I don't control the proc; how do I get a decent error message out of it?

Comment: The additional edits were just meant to give more context to the scenario, IE) i dont have `XACT_ABORT` on, the reason of the failure. 
I don't own the stored proc so I can't make any changes to it, and I don't see any severity levels in the exceptions i am getting. 


So given that the `INSERT` fails because of a null value, and the statements aren't in a transaction or try/catch, will the `UPDATE` still execute?

Comment: For a NULL value - Yes. For a duplicate key - YES. Out of disk space - MAYBE (NO if on same disk). Database is corrupt - NO. For most scenarios, yes, the update will still run. I've added information to my answer about how an admin could make simple changes to allow you to see the errors (this is a very non-ideal method but quick and dirty enough that admin might actually do it ... I've been there)

Comment: Thanks again for your help Alan! Your info gave me the understanding I needed! Everything worked out well now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potentially. It depends on the severity level of the fail.

User code errors are normally 16.

Anything over 20 is an automatic fail.

Duplicate key blocking insert would be 14 i.e. non-fatal.

Inserting a NULL into a column which does not support it - this is counted as a user code error (16) - and consequently will not cause the batch to halt. The `UPDATE` will go ahead.

The other major factor would be if the batch has a configuration of XACT_ABORT to ON. This will cause any failure to abort the whole batch.

Here's some further reading:

[list-of-errors-and-severity-level-in-sql-server-with-catalog-view-sysmessages](http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2013/01/29/list-of-errors-and-severity-level-in-sql-server-with-catalog-view-sysmessages/)

[exceptionerror-handling-in-sql-server](http://sqlhints.com/tag/exceptionerror-handling-in-sql-server-2000200520082012/)

And for the XACT_ABORT

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/defensive-error-handling/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql

In order to understand the outcome of any of the steps in the stored procedure, someone with appropriate permissions (e.g. an admin) will need to edit the stored proc and capture the error message. This will give feedback as to the progress of the stored proc. An unstructured error (i.e. not in try/catch) code of 0 indicates success, otherwise it will contain the error code (which I think will be 515 for NULL insertion). This is non-ideal as mentioned in the comments, as it still won't cause the batch to halt, but it will warn you that there was an issue.

The most simple example:

```
DECLARE @errnum AS int;
-- Run the insert code
SET @errnum = @@ERROR;
PRINT 'Error code: ' + CAST(@errornum AS VARCHAR);
```

Error handling can be a complicated issue; it requires significant understanding of the database structure and expected incoming data.

Options can include using an intermediate step (as mentioned by HLGEM), amending the `INSERT` to include `ISNULL / COALESCE` statements to purge nulls, checking the data on the client side to remove troublesome issues etc. If you know the number of rows you are expecting to insert, the stored proc can return `SET @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT` in the same way as `SET @errnum = @@ERROR`.

If you have no authority over the stored proc and no ability to persuade the admin to amend it ... there's not a great deal you can do.

If you have access to run your own queries directly against the database (instead of only through stored proc or views) then you might be able to infer the outcome by running your own query against the original data, performing the stored proc update, then re-running your query and looking for changes. If you have permission, you could also try querying the transaction log (`fn_dblog`) or the error log (`sp_readerrorlog`).

Comment: Thanks for all your info! XACT_ABORT is OFF for me. I only have access to the exception my program threw, and I didn't see severity levels. 
The reason the `INSERT` failed is because I passed in a null value to a column that doesn't accept nulls.

Comment: The thing is for data integrity reasons, you usually want all steps to rollback if one fails. So I personally would fix the stored proc to do that and to properly bubble up the error.  If you create a table variable to store information on the steps or the data being entered or the errors and populate after each step, when you rollback that info is still available and can be inserted into a real table so that you can look up exactly what happened.

Comment: See also detailed behaviour description at http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification